# How can I trigger an explicit UI update in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a qml application which performs a rather long action upon a users request. During the time, I want to display an overlay over the whole screen, so the user is aware that the application is working, basically a busy indicator.

My Problem is, that the application starts with the task, before updating the UI component. Here's a minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Ui Demo")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"    
    }


    MouseArea {
        id: action

        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rectangle.color = "red"
            for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                console.log(i)
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is, that the `Rectangle`s color turns red while the `for` loop is running, but the behavior I see is that the color changes only after the loop has finished.

I also tried the following with no difference:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "green"

    onColorChanged: {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            console.log(i)
    }
}
```

I know, that the cleanest solution would be to perform the heavy work on a different thread to not block the UI thread. But I do not wish to do this, because in my actual application the blocking work is updating a ListModel, which (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482599/how-can-i-query-asynchronously-via-a-qsqlquerymodel) for example)

> Qt views unfortunately don't know how to deal with [when they are] in foreign threads.

So [I would need to implement a new, asynchronous Model class](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/64516-Asynchronous-database-operations), which is effort and time my customer is currently not willing to pay for.

Therefor my question is: **How can I make sure, that the UI is redrawn/updated as soon as I set the property?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to use transform the sequential logic of the *"for"* to an asynchronous logic through a `Timer`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Ui Demo")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
    }


    MouseArea {
        id: action

        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rectangle.color = "red"
            timer.start()
        }
    }
    Timer{
        id: timer
        interval: 1
        property int counter: 0
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            counter += 1
            console.log(counter)
            if(counter > 100000)
                timer.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about using a Timer, but scratched the idea as I did not want to delay execution. For some reason though I did not think about an interval of 1... `>.<` I slightly [adapted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50945027/2865814) your solution to match my real code a little better and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Reliable Workaround

Thanks to eyllanesc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944720/2865814) I figured out a possible solution.
I use a single shot timer, to start my work, because in the actual code I cannot call different steps with a repeating timer - but I do not need to anyway, as I don't want to display any animated UI elements. This code works for my purposes:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Ui Demo")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
    }


    MouseArea {
        id: action

        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rectangle.color = "red"
            timer.start()
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer

        interval: 1
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                console.log(i)
            rectangle.color = "green"
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a Timer - even with only a 1 msec interval - grants the logic with the processing time to change the color, before starting with the actual work. While this looks like a slightly hacky workaround it works just fine.

## More elegant though less reliable approach

There is a cleaner, though less reliable solution:
Qts [`callLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method) function seems to be sort of what I was looking for. Even though the official documentation seems incomplete, I found the function documentation in [its source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/qml/qml/v8/qqmlbuiltinfunctions.cpp):

> Use this function to eliminate redundant calls to a function or signal.
>
> The function passed as the first argument to Qt.callLater()
>   will be called later, once the QML engine returns to the event loop.
>
> When this function is called multiple times in quick succession with the
>   same function as its first argument, that function will be called only once.
>
> For example:
>   \snippet qml/qtLater.qml 0
>
> Any additional arguments passed to Qt.callLater() will
>   be passed on to the function invoked. Note that if redundant calls
>   are eliminated, then only the last set of arguments will be passed to the
>   function.

Using the call later function delayed the call to the working code *most of the time* for long enough so that the UI would get updated. However about a third of the times, this would fail and show the same behavior as described in the question.

This approach can be implemented like the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Ui Demo")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
    }


    MouseArea {
        id: action

        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rectangle.color = "red"
            Qt.callLater(action.doWork)
        }

        function doWork() {
            for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                console.log(i)
            rectangle.color = "green"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using [`Qt.callLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method) seems more appropriate.

Comment: @GrecKo That's pretty much exactly what I was hoping for, but a quick test makes it look like occasionally "later" isn't late enough, and the Ui again is not updated early enough.

Comment: I also found Qt.callLater() works most of the time, but, not all the time.