# Cleanly closing a QSerialPort in Qt

Tags: windows, multithreading, qt, qt5.4, qtserialport

I am trying to close a serial port opened using the QSerialPort library but it hangs more than half the time.

I am developing a multi-threaded app, with one thread responsible for UI and the other for serial communication. I am using the QThread wrapper class.

```
    void CommThread::run()
{
    serial = new QSerialPort();

    serial->setPortName(portname);
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);

    if(!serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        qDebug() << "Error opening Serial port within thread";
        quit = true;
        return;
    }else{
        /// \todo handle this exception more gracefully
    }

    /// Start our reading loop
    /// While CommThread::disconnect is not called, this loop will run
    while(!quit){
        comm_mutex->lock();

        /// If CommThread::disconnect() is called send DISCONNECT Packet
        if(dconnect){
            // Signal device to disconnect so that it can suspend USB CDC transmission of data
            qDebug() << "Entering disconnect sequence";

            serial->write(data);
            serial->flush();

            break;
        }

        /// No write or disconnect requested
        /// Read incoming data from port
        if(serial->waitForReadyRead(-1)){
            if(serial->canReadLine()){
              // Read stuff here
            }
        }

        // Transform the stuff read here

        comm_mutex->lock()
        // Do something to a shared data structure 
        // emit signal to main thread that data is ready           
        comm_mutex->unlock();
    }

    comm_mutex->unlock();

    // Thread is exiting, clean up resources it created
    qDebug() << "Thread ID" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    qDebug() << "Thread:: Closing and then deleting the serial port";
    qDebug() << "Lets check the error string" << serial->errorString();
    delete comm_mutex;
    serial->close();
    qDebug() << "Thread:: Port closed";
    delete serial;
    qDebug() << "Thread:: Serial deleted";
    delete img;
    qDebug() << "Thread:: Image deleted";
    qDebug() << "Thread:: Serial port and img memory deleted";
    quit = true;

}
```

The problem is when the UI thread sets the dconnect variable to true and proceeds to delete the communication thread it gets stuck in the destructor of the communication thread which looks like this:

```
    CommThread::~CommThread()
{
    qDebug() << "Destructor waiting for thread to stop";
    QThread::wait();
    qDebug() << "Destuctor Commthread ID" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    qDebug() << "Commthread wrapper exiting";
}
```

2 out of three times, the communication thread hangs at the `serial-close()` line, causing the UI thread to hang at the `QThread::wait()` line in the destructor. Needless to say this results in a frozen UI and if closed, the entire application remains in memory until killed by the task manager. Given a few minutes the call to serial::close() will finally return; what I would like to know is what's wrong and how can I best avoid a hanging UI?

I have looked into the code of QSerialPort and I can't see anything manifestly wrong. If I call `serial->errorCode()` I get the UknownError string but that happens even when the port closes with no hangups.

**EDIT**: This NEVER happens in the debugger. The SerialPort always closes immediately and the destructor sails through with no hangups on QThread::wait()

**EDIT**: I am certain it is the serial->close() which is hanging because I can see the qDebug() statement being printed just before it hangs for several seconds or minutes).

The device stops transmitting because in the dconnect switch, a disconnect packet is sent and a LED on the device turns green.

Comment: You have two obvious threading bugs.  One is the dconnect variable, a bool is not a proper synchronization primitive.  The other is waitForReadyReady(), you'll never recognize the attempt to disconnect when the device is not transmitting data.  The Q&D fix is to just not bother.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include all the code: dconnect is protected by the mutex, just as the shared resource the communication thread is writing to and the UI thread is reading from. 

    waitforReadRead(-1)
 is to make the serial port blocking. The device is guratneed to always be transmitting data.

Comment: "The device is guratneed to always be transmitting data." Don't depend on this. It most likely never happen in the debugger because only in the debugger you really know that the code is performing the `close()` and not stuck somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse but I do know the code is stuck in the close() because I can see it in the qDebug statements I have littered all over the place. The code stops immediately at "Thread:: Closing and then deleting the serial port"; meanwhile the UI gets stuck at QThread::wait(), as soon as the serial->close() call returns, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: it looks like your mutex might be double locked.  This could prevent it from getting deleted.  So instead of a problem with your `serial->close` function it may be your mutex usage.  I really like the `QMutexLocker` because it doesn't have the typical issues with unlocking, because it uses scope to unlock.

Comment: Thanks @phyatt, have tried moving delete mutex to before the comment and still no change, the code hangs on serial->close. Is it possibly a drive issue that has nothing to do with my code?

Comment: Design your code so that you accept the fact that `close`, or any other `QSerialPort` methods, can block for extended amounts of time. See my answer. And really, write idiomatic C++11, what you show up there is such a bad mix of C and C++ that your code might be failing simply because you mess up somewhere else. You might have destroyed the `QSerialPort` instance's state or used it wrong and it results in the `close` block that you experience. How would we know if you don't show a complete example that reproduces the issue for you? Help us help you!

Comment: If things don't happen under the debugger, then it could be that you had races in your code... Debug builds change the timing.

Comment: That is as much code as I can include without getting into trouble & I have included all references to the QSerialPort. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Galaxy If this code causes the serial port to block on close, then you can put it in a single `main.cpp` and convince us thus of that :)

Comment: @KubaOber I'll try that if I get the time. Is it any clue if I say serial.close() returns immediately if I pull the USB port out when it hangs? And why the downvote?

Comment: `wait()` should not be called in destructor of your `QThread` derived class because it could happen that the thread waits on itself. This will lock for ever. It tends to be a good idea to use `QThread` message loop and not use the run method directly to perform to work. `void DoWorkInThread() {if (thread() != QThread::currentThread()) { QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "DoWorkInThread", Qt::QueuedConnection);} else {/* Do real work here */}}` In order to work, the thread object has to be moved to this new Thread first in ctor for example like `moveToThread(this);`.

Comment: @bkausbk "it could happen that the thread waits on itself" It's trivial to check that, but generally speaking the `moveToThread(this)` is such an antipattern that you should not have to cope with it. At best simply assert that it's not so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things:

1. You can certainly simply leak the port if it doesn't close soon enough.
2. You should perform a graceful exit where the UI is responsive and the thread shutdown is attempted with a timeout.
3. You should use smart pointers and other RAII techniques to manage resources. This is C++, not C. Ideally, store things by value, not through a pointer.
4. You must not block in the of the sections where you modify the shared data structure(s) under a lock.
5. You should be notifying of changes to the data structure (perhaps you do). How can other code depend on such changes without polling otherwise? It can't, and polling is horrible for performance.
6. `QThread` offers `requestInterruption` and `isInterruptionRequested` for code that reimplements `run` without an event loop. Use it, don't roll your won `quit` flags.
7. Your code would be much simpler if you had used a `QObject` directly.

At the very minimum, we want a UI that won't block on a worker thread being shut down. We start with a thread implementation that has the functionality needed to support such a UI.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/serial-test-32331713
#include <QtWidgets>

/// A thread that gives itself a bit of time to finish up, and then terminates.
class Thread : public QThread {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY (int shutdownTimeout MEMBER m_shutdownTimeout)
   int m_shutdownTimeout { 1000 }; ///< in milliseconds
   QBasicTimer m_shutdownTimer;
   void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) override {
      if (ev->timerId() == m_shutdownTimer.timerId()) {
         if (! isFinished()) terminate();
      }
      QThread::timerEvent(ev);
   }
   bool event(QEvent *event) override {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::ThreadChange)
         QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::None));
      else if (event->type() == QEvent::None && thread() == currentThread())
         // Hint that moveToThread(this) is an antipattern
         qWarning() << "The thread controller" << this << "is running in its own thread.";
      return QThread::event(event);
   }
   using QThread::requestInterruption; ///< Hidden, use stop() instead.
   using QThread::quit; ///< Hidden, use stop() instead.
public:
   Thread(QObject * parent = 0) : QThread(parent) {
      connect(this, &QThread::finished, this, [this]{ m_shutdownTimer.stop(); });
   }
   /// Indicates that the thread is attempting to finish.
   Q_SIGNAL void stopping();
   /// Signals the thread to stop in a general way.
   Q_SLOT void stop() {
      emit stopping();
      m_shutdownTimer.start(m_shutdownTimeout, this);
      requestInterruption(); // should break a run() that has no event loop
      quit();                // should break the event loop if there is one
   }
   ~Thread() {
      Q_ASSERT(!thread() || thread() == QThread::currentThread());
      stop();
      wait(50);
      if (isRunning()) terminate();
      wait();
   }
};
```

It's a bit of a lie that `Thread` is-a `QThread` since we cannot use some of the base class's members on it, thus breaking the LSP. Ideally, `Thread` should be a `QObject`, and only internally contain a `QThread`.

We then implement a dummy thread that takes its time to terminate, and can optionally get stuck permanently, just like your code sometime does (although it doesn't have to).

```
class LazyThread : public Thread {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(bool getStuck MEMBER m_getStuck)
   bool m_getStuck { false };
   void run() override {
      while (!isInterruptionRequested()) {
         msleep(100); // pretend that we're busy
      }
      qDebug() << "loop exited";
      if (m_getStuck) {
         qDebug() << "stuck";
         Q_FOREVER sleep(1);
      } else {
         qDebug() << "a little nap";
         sleep(2);
      }
   }
public:
   LazyThread(QObject * parent = 0) : Thread(parent) {
      setProperty("shutdownTimeout", 5000);
   }
};
```

We then need a class that can link up worker threads and UI close requests. It installs itself as an event filter on the main window, and delays its closing until all threads have terminated.

```
class CloseThreadStopper : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QSet<Thread*> m_threads;
   void done(Thread* thread ){
      m_threads.remove(thread);
      if (m_threads.isEmpty()) emit canClose();
   }
   bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev) override {
      if (ev->type() == QEvent::Close) {
         bool close = true;
         for (auto thread : m_threads) {
            if (thread->isRunning() && !thread->isFinished()) {
               close = false;
               ev->ignore();
               connect(thread, &QThread::finished, this, [this, thread]{ done(thread); });
               thread->stop();
            }
         }
         return !close;
      }
      return false;
   }
public:
   Q_SIGNAL void canClose();
   CloseThreadStopper(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
   void addThread(Thread* thread) {
      m_threads.insert(thread);
      connect(thread, &QObject::destroyed, this, [this, thread]{ done(thread); });
   }
   void installOn(QWidget * w) {
      w->installEventFilter(this);
      connect(this, &CloseThreadStopper::canClose, w, &QWidget::close);
   }
};
```

Finally, we have a simple UI that allows us to control all this and see that it works. At no point is the UI unresponsive or blocked.

[image: screenshot]

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a { argc, argv };
   LazyThread thread;
   CloseThreadStopper stopper;
   stopper.addThread(&thread);

   QWidget ui;
   QGridLayout layout { &ui };
   QLabel state;
   QPushButton start { "Start" }, stop { "Stop" };
   QCheckBox stayStuck { "Keep the thread stuck" };
   layout.addWidget(&state, 0, 0, 1, 2);
   layout.addWidget(&stayStuck, 1, 0, 1, 2);
   layout.addWidget(&start, 2, 0);
   layout.addWidget(&stop, 2, 1);
   stopper.installOn(&ui);
   QObject::connect(&stayStuck, &QCheckBox::toggled, &thread, [&thread](bool v){
      thread.setProperty("getStuck", v);
   });

   QStateMachine sm;
   QState s_started { &sm }, s_stopping { &sm }, s_stopped { &sm };
   sm.setGlobalRestorePolicy(QState::RestoreProperties);
   s_started.assignProperty(&state, "text", "Running");
   s_started.assignProperty(&start, "enabled", false);
   s_stopping.assignProperty(&state, "text", "Stopping");
   s_stopping.assignProperty(&start, "enabled", false);
   s_stopping.assignProperty(&stop, "enabled", false);
   s_stopped.assignProperty(&state, "text", "Stopped");
   s_stopped.assignProperty(&stop, "enabled", false);

   for (auto state : { &s_started, &s_stopping })
      state->addTransition(&thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &s_stopped);
   s_started.addTransition(&thread, SIGNAL(stopping()), &s_stopping);
   s_stopped.addTransition(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), &s_started);
   QObject::connect(&start, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{ thread.start(); });
   QObject::connect(&stop, &QPushButton::clicked, &thread, &Thread::stop);
   sm.setInitialState(&s_stopped);

   sm.start();
   ui.show();
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Given the `Thread` class, and following advice above (other than point 7), your `run()` should look roughly as follows:

```
class CommThread : public Thread {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   enum class Request { Disconnect };
private:
   QMutex m_mutex;
   QQueue<Request> m_requests;
   //...
   void run() override;
};

void CommThread::run()
{
   QString portname;
   QSerialPort port;

   port.setPortName(portname);
   port.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);

   if (!port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
      qWarning() << "Error opening Serial port within thread";
      return;
   }

   while (! isInterruptionRequested()) {
      QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
      if (! m_requests.isEmpty()) {
         auto request = m_requests.dequeue();
         lock.unlock();
         if (request == Request::Disconnect) {
            qDebug() << "Entering disconnect sequence";
            QByteArray data;
            port.write(data);
            port.flush();
         }
         //...
      }
      lock.unlock();

      // The loop must run every 100ms to check for new requests
      if (port.waitForReadyRead(100)) {
         if (port.canReadLine()) {
            //...
         }
         QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
         // Do something to a shared data structure
      }

      qDebug() << "The thread is exiting";
   }
}
```

Of course, this is a truly horrible style that unnecessarily spins the loop waiting for things to happen, etc. Instead, the trivial way to approach such issues is to have a `QObject` with a thread-safe interface that can be moved to a worker thread.

First, a curiously recurring helper; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21646467/1329652) for details.

```
namespace {
template <typename F>
static void postTo(QObject * obj, F && fun) {
   QObject signalSource;
   QObject::connect(&signalSource, &QObject::destroyed, obj, std::forward<F>(fun),
                    Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
}
```

We derive from `QObject` and use `postTo` to execute functors from our thread's event loop.

```
class CommObject : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image NOTIFY imageChanged)
   mutable QMutex m_imageMutex;
   QImage m_image;
   QByteArray m_data;
   QString m_portName;
   QSerialPort m_port { this };
   void onData() {
      if (m_port.canReadLine()) {
         // process the line
      }
      QMutexLocker lock(&m_imageMutex);
      // Do something to the image
      emit imageChanged(m_image);
   }
public:
   /// Thread-safe
   Q_SLOT void disconnect() {
      postTo(this, [this]{
         qDebug() << "Entering disconnect sequence";
         m_port.write(m_data);
         m_port.flush();
      });
   }
   /// Thread-safe
   Q_SLOT void open() {
      postTo(this, [this]{
         m_port.setPortName(m_portName);
         m_port.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
         if (!m_port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
            qWarning() << "Error opening the port";
            emit openFailed();
         } else {
            emit opened();
         }
      });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void opened();
   Q_SIGNAL void openFailed();
   Q_SIGNAL void imageChanged(const QImage &);
   CommObject(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
      open();
      connect(&m_port, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &CommObject::onData);
   }
   QImage image() const {
      QMutexLocker lock(&m_imageMutex);
      return m_image;
   }
};
```

Let's observe that any `QIODevice` automatically closes on destruction. Thus all we need to do to close the port is to destruct it, in the desired worker thread so that the long operation doesn't block the UI.

Thus, we really want the object (and its port) to be deleted in its thread (or leak). This is simply accomplished by connecting `Thread::stopping` to the object's `deleteLater` slot. There, the port closing can take as much time as needed - the `Thread` will terminate its execution if it times out. All the while the UI remains responsive.

```
int main(...) {
  //...
  Thread thread;
  thread.start();
  QScopedPointer<CommObject> comm(new CommObject);
  comm->moveToThread(&thread);
  QObject::connect(&thread, &Thread::stopping, comm.take(), &QObject::deleteLater);
  //...
}
```