# Qt dynamic stylesheet with User Interface Compiler

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working with a Qt application that uses an XML file to generate the user interface, via the Qt User Interface Compiler.

I don't have access to the code that holds each widget (I do but the Qt UI Compiler re-generates it each time), so I'm not able to add another method to the class that it generates.

I'm trying to do a setStyleSheet on one of the QLineEdit widgets, but it gives me a `QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread` warning and then eventually seg faults. After resigning myself to not being able to go this route, I decided to test having two copies of each widget, each with the stylesheet values needed. I would then trigger a `QLineEdit::hide()` and `QLineEdit::show()` on the widgets as needed, which I thought would work.

It didn't. The program now spits out `QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread` whenever run.

What can I do to fix this? I need to change the stylesheet of the widget dynamically, but seem unable to do so in any manner.

Comment: Are you in the main thread (the one where `QApplication` instance was started) when you try to apply the stylesheet?

Comment: I'm not. It's in a separate thread. It allows me to change the value of the text via `setText("text")`, but I can't set the stylesheet.

Comment: No suprise then if it crashs, check Kuba's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't be invoking any `QWidget` methods from threads other than the main thread. It's fairly easy to indirectly invoke such methods safely from any thread, though. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/1329652) for details.

For example, suppose you wanted to call `setStyleSheet` on a widget, from code that runs in some other thread:

```
template <typename F>
static void postToMainThread(F && fun, QObject * object) {
   QObject signalSource;
   QObject::connect(&signalSource, &QObject::destroyed, object, std::forward(fun));
}

void threadCode(QWidget * widget) {
  postToMainThread([widget]{
    widget->setStyleSheet("color: black");
  }, widget);
}
```

Comment: I've tried to wade through that answer linked, and can't seem to understand how the signal/slot was set up.
If I need to set up a signal to send to the main thread to update the stylesheet, how would I got about that?

I understand the concept of Signals and Slots, and understand how to connect them. My issue is with making one for a QLineEdit (or any widget). It doesn't seem as though they have any signal that I can use to send to the setStyleSheet slot.

Comment: @JoshJohnson You don't need any signals at all, that's taken care of by examples. What you're executing is a functor - a self contained chunk of code - in the main thread. The first section of the answer has everything you need. The `F` template type is meant to be a functor or a function pointer. Pass it a lambda with your code to run, and you're done.