# QtConcurrent::run with MainWindow function, warning message "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread"

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I'm trying to use QtConcurrent::run to execute a function within my MainWindow class, so that the UI remains responsive during the calculations. Here is how I implemented it:

```
    void MainWindow::on_calculate_pb_clicked()
    {
        QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::calculation);
    }

    void MainWindow::calculation()
    {
        progressBar->show();
        loadMap();
        integral.clear();
        positions.clear();
        offset.clear();
        lines = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<paths.size();i++)
        {
            if(i ==0)
            {
                lines = countNumberOfLines(paths.at(i));
            }
            double file = i+1;
            ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString("Processing file %1 of %2").arg(file).arg(paths.size()));

            calculateIntegral(paths.at(i));
            offset.push_back(ui->tableWidget->item(i,1)->text().toDouble());
        }
        makePositionVector();

        plotData(ui->customPlot);
        ui->export_pb->setEnabled(true);
        progressBar->hide();
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Done",3000);

    }

    void MainWindow::calculateIntegral(QString path)
    {
        QVector<double> mappeddata,tempdata;
        mappeddata.resize(map.size());
        tempdata.resize(numberofdetectors);

        double currentLine = 0;

        QFile File(path);
        if(File.exists()==true){
            File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
            QTextStream in(&File);
            double val;

            while(!in.atEnd())
            {
                for(int j = 0;j<numberofdetectors;j++)
                {
                    in >> val;
                    tempdata[j]+=val;
                    currentLine++;
                    double progress = currentLine/lines*100;
                    progressBar->setValue(progress);
                }

            }

            for(int i =0;i<map.size();i++)
            {
                mappeddata[i] = tempdata.at(map.at(i));
            }
            for(int k = 0;k<numberofdetectors; k++)
            {
                integral.push_back(mappeddata.at(k));
            }

        }
        File.close();
    }
```

It works fine and the UI is responsive and the progress bar is updated correctly, however in the output I receive the error "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread" many times, from something that is executing in a loop.

Any ideas what is causing this, or suggestions for a better implementation of QtConcurrent::run?

Thanks

Comment: the problem is that you are updating the UI from threads other than the main thread. See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#example-use-cases), Run the function using QtConcurrent::run(),  *Write to a thread-safe variable to update progress*.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/44153/access-to-components-of-ui-from-the-function-of-qtconcurrent-run-foo/2

Comment: perfect thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't be touching any Qt-provided `QWidget` objects from the worker thread, since most of their methods are not thread-safe.

Instead, a way to tackle this is to do the computations in the worker, and then submit functors that update the state to the main thread. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/1329652) for details.

Your code would then become:

```
void MainWindow::calculation()
{
    postToThread([this]{ progressBar->show(); });
    loadMap();
    integral.clear();
    positions.clear();
    offset.clear();
    lines = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<paths.size();i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            lines = countNumberOfLines(paths.at(i));
        auto file = i+1;
        postToThread([this]{
            ui->statusBar->showMessage(
              tr("Processing file %1 of %2").arg(file).arg(paths.size()));
        });
        calculateIntegral(paths.at(i));
        postToThread([this]{
          offset.push_back(ui->tableWidget->item(i,1)->text().toDouble());
        });
    }
    makePositionVector();

    postToThread([this]{
      plotData(ui->customPlot);
      ui->export_pb->setEnabled(true);
      progressBar->hide();
      ui->statusBar->showMessage("Done",3000);
    });
}
```

Modify the `calculateIntegral` in a similar fashion, but make sure that you don't emit progress updates too often.

Also make sure that the members that you update from the worker are not accessed elsewhere by the UI code. This can be hard since you mix UI and computations. Instead, abstract the worker out to a `QObject` that has no UI, and interface it to other code via signals that indicate progress/status. You will still use `QtConcurrent::run` within that object, but it becomes simpler to assure that no other threads access that object's private state.

To push finished results out of the worker functor, you can emit a signal that carries the results. The `Data` type should be cheap to copy, e.g. you can implement it using `QSharedData`/`QSharedDataPointer`. Or you can hold it via a `QSharedPointer`.

```
class Computation : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  void work() {
    Data data;
    ... // updates data
    emit finished(data);
  }
public:
  Q_SLOT void compute() {
    QtConcurrent::run(&Worker::work, this);
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void finished(Data data);
};
```

You can also store the results in the object, and pay attention that they are not accessed while the computations are active:

```
class Computation : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  bool m_active { false };
  Data m_data;
  void work() {
    ... // updates m_data
    m_active = false;
  }
public:
  Q_SLOT void compute() {
    m_active = true;
    QtConcurrent::run(&Worker::work, this);
  }
  const Data & data() const {
    Q_ASSERT(! m_active);
    return m_data;
  }
};
```

Of course, if you store the reference to `data()` in the main thread and then call `compute()`, you'll have undefined behavior, so don't do that.

If any of the data types are an implicitly shared container, like `QVector` or `QString`, you should return them by value, and any access will be thread-safe:

```
  QVector<MyData> data() const {
    Q_ASSERT(! m_active);
   return m_data;
  }
```

---

Note that `QFile` is a proper C++ class. It releases any resources held when it gets destructed. Closing the file manually is unnecessary: the compiler is supposed to help you here, that's the whole point of C++'s object model as compared to e.g. Java's.