# How to invoke method by function pointer?

Tags: qt

Invoking a method

Normal way :

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "function");
```

But instead of using string.This is what I want :

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, function());
// or any macro like SLOT
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, FUNC_NAME(function()));
```

Comment: Why using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` istead of directly call the method by `obj.func()`?

Comment: @putu For example, invoke a method in the different thread.

Comment: Specifically, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/1329652) look for the  "TL;DR for methods/slots"

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly** recommend you to use the normal way, i.e. using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "function")`. However, if you want you can use the following stringify macro:

```
#define FUNC_NAME(a)         (QString(#a).remove(QRegExp("\\((.*)\\)")).trimmed().toLatin1().constData())

//usage
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, FUNC_NAME(function()));
```

The above macro convert argument to string then remove method/function arguments between `(...)`.

Comment: The stringify macro provides no compile-time protection against a change in the function signature, unlike the Qt 5.10 function pointer syntax overloads which result in compiler errors if the function name does not exist.