# Change listen port not on main thread in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a problem with modifying the port number while the socket is listening for python clients. This is for an application on Windows.

Does anyone know if it's possible to stop a port from listening, from the main thread, while the port listening is in another thread?

The socket lives in its own thread, not the main thread. And I can not modify a socket from other thread than current thread. I tried by using signals and slots but it did not work. I am using the thread-worker approach currently. Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: C++ code in Qt creator

Comment: @JokerMartini,  how a bout connect each thread to a signal you own in main thread ... fired when you want stop listing ? .. any obstacle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The target thread must be an unmodified `QThread`, i.e. it must spin an event loop.
2. The socket I/O should reside in a `QObject` that you have moved to that thread.
3. You can then [easily execute arbitrary code in the target thread, invoked from any other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21646467/1329652).